# How to know if the last row of the ListView is displayed fully?

Tags: android, listview

I know how to check if the last row of the ListView is visible. However, being visible doesn't guarantee that the row is displayed fully. How can I check if the last row is displayed fully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to compare the height of the ListView to the bottom position of the footer.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    if(arg1 + arg2 == arg3) //If last row is visible. In this case, the last row is the footer.
    {
        if(footer != null) //footer is a variable referencing the footer view of the ListView. You need to initialize this onCreate
        {
            if(listView.getHeight() == footer.getBottom()) //Check if the whole footer is visible.
                doThisMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

For the interest of others, the footer is basically a `View` which I added to the `ListView` via the `addFooterView`. `R.layout.footer` is the layout for the footer. Below is a sample code on how I initialize the footer and added it on the `ListView`:

```
View footer; //This is a global variable.
....
//Inside onCreate or any method where you initialize your layouts
footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Comment: Can you please add code of footer here ? How to initialize footer in onCreate method ?

Comment: @Jayesh: Hi! I updated my answer to include the code on how I initialized the footer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like (not tested):

```
if (listView.getScrollY() == listView.getMaxScrollAmount()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this inside onScroll() but listView.getScrollY() always returns a value of 0. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Sounds like a bug in the OS itself.

Comment: I'm using Android API 8. Is there a bug on getScrollY in API 8?